# Using Spring threading and TaskExecutor, how do I know when a thread is finished?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

Alright, possible a naive question here. I have a service that needs to log into multiple network devices, run a command on each and collect the results.  For speed, rather than collect the information on each device in sequence, I need to access them all concurrently and consume the results after they are done.

Using the Spring framework and Jsch I'm quite easily able to query each device correctly.  Where I am running into some confusion is in trying to rewire the beans to use TaskExecutor to accomplish this. What I can't figure out how to do is how to know when the thread is finished.

What I have so far is this:

```
public class RemoteCommand {

    private String user;
    private String host;
    private String password;
    private String command;
    private List<String> commandResults;
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public RemoteCommand(String user, String host, String password, TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {

        setUser(user);
        setHost(host);
        setPassword(password);
        setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    }

    /**
     * @param user the user to set
     */
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    /**
     * @return the user
     */
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * @param host the host to set
     */
    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    /**
     * @return the host
     */
    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param command the command to set
     */
    private void setCommand(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    /**
     * @return the command
     */
    private String getCommand() {
        return command;
    }

    /**
     * @param commandResults the commandResults to set
     */
    private void setCommandResults(List<String> commandResults) {
        this.commandResults = commandResults;
    }

    /**
     * @return the commandResults
     */
    public List<String> getCommandResults(String command) {
        taskExecutor.execute(new CommandTask(command) );

        return commandResults;
    }

    /**
     * @param taskExecutor the taskExecutor to set
     */
    public void setTaskExecutor(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }

    /**
     * @return the taskExecutor
     */
    public TaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    private class CommandTask implements Runnable {

        public CommandTask(String command) {
            setCommand(command);
            System.out.println("test: " + getCommand());
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param command
         */
        public void run() {

            List<String> results = new LinkedList<String>();
            String command = getCommand();

            try {
                System.out.println("running");
                JSch jsch = new JSch();

                String user = getUser();
                String host = getHost();

                java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
                config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

                host = host.substring(host.indexOf('@') + 1);
                Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

                session.setPassword(getPassword());
                session.setConfig(config);
                session.connect();

                Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
                ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

                channel.setInputStream(null);

                ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

                InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

                channel.connect();
                byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
                while (true) {
                    while (in.available() > 0) {
                        int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                        if (i < 0)
                            break;
                        results.add(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                    }
                    if (channel.isClosed()) {
                        //System.out.println("exit-status: "
                        //      + channel.getExitStatus());
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                        ee.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                channel.disconnect();
                session.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            setCommandResults(results);
            System.out.println("finished running");
        }
    }
}
```

Within my junit test I have:

```
@Test
    public void testRemoteExecution() {

        remoteCommand = (RemoteCommand) applicationContext.getBean("remoteCommand");
        remoteCommand.getCommandResults("scripts/something.pl xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");

            //List<String> results = remoteCommand.getCommandResults("scripts/something.pl xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
        //for (String line : results) {
        //  System.out.println(line.trim());
        //}
    }
```

My applicationContext.xml file:

```
    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
       <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
       <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
       <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
    </bean>        

<!-- ******************** -->
<!--      Utilities       -->
<!-- ******************** -->

     <bean name="remoteCommand" class="com.xxx.ncc.sonet.utilities.RemoteCommand" scope="prototype">
        <description>Remote Command</description>
        <constructor-arg><value>${remote.user}</value></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg><value>${remote.host}</value></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg><value>${remote.password}</value></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg ref="taskExecutor" />
    </bean>
```

I get as far as the first println in the run() method. Then the test exits cleanly with no errors. I never get to the second println at the bottom of that routine. I've looked at this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702415/how-to-know-if-other-threads-have-finished), which was very useful, but not implemented in a Spring specific fashion.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, or have completely run off the rails here.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public List<String> getCommandResults(String command) {
    FutureTask task = new FutureTask(new CommandTask(command))
    taskExecutor.execute(task);

    return task.get(); //or task.get(); return commandResults; - but it not a good practice
}
```

Comment: `FutureTask` has no such constructor... it either takes a `Callable`, or a `Runnable` with a pre-computed result.

Comment: Oh, yes, it is. I just forgot to say that it's better to make CommandTask as Callable. sorry

Answer (score 51):

The `TaskExecutor` interface is a fire-and-forget interface, for use when you don't care when the task finishes. It's the simplest async abstraction that Spring offers.

There is , however, an enhanced interface, [`AsyncTaskExecutor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)), which provides additional methods, including `submit()` methods that return a `Future`, which let you wait on the result.

Spring provides the [`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) class, which implement both `TaskExecutor` and `AsyncTaskExecutor`.

In your specific case, I would re-implement the `Runnable` as a `Callable`, and return the `commandResults` from the `Callable.call()` method. The `getCommandResults` method can then be reimplemented as:

```
public List<String> getCommandResults(String command) {
   Future<List<String>> futureResults = taskExecutor.submit(new CommandTask(command));
   return futureResults.get();
}
```

This method will submit the task asynchronously, and then wait for it to complete before returning the results returned from the `Callable.call()` method. This also lets you get rid of the `commandResults` field.

Comment: A very helpful answer.  It was the final answer above that completed the fix, but I wouldn't have fully understood it with out your answer, thanks.