# How to wait for spring cron job to be finished from ant build script

Tags: java, spring, deployment, cron

Say my web app has two spring cron jobs scheduled to run every minute/hour. Before I'm redeploying my app I can't just shut it down, I must wait for jobs to be finished correctly. I can provide some flag in database or somewhere else, so that jobs will stop to run iteratively - every minute or hour - put some check inside job function to return/do nothing on the next trigger call if such flag checked.

But how can I wait for current job call to finish? And how to see it from ant or other outside script - to choose good time for server shutdown.

There may be solution to put some flag in db or file, and read it. But may be there is some more accurate way - jms or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the database you can use JMX. -- But in my humble opinion: If you already use a database but no JMX yet, then use a DB flag, or a simple file, to signal the timer to "stop".

More nice than using the flag and check for every invocation if the flag is set would be shoting [`shutdown()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/backportconcurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#shutdown%28%29) down the `ThreadPoolTaskSchedule` or `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.
But this would require a second task (run every minute or shorter) to check the flag and then shutdown to scheduler.

To make the ant task wait for a timespan, after setting the flag, to make sure that the last task is done, you can use the [WaitFor](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/waitfor.html) task.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `TaskExecutor` to run the "cron" jobs, then you could use the method described by skaffman in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2269177/320220) to get the results of the task execution. If you need access to this from ant, you could probably use spring's [JMS support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/reference/html/jms.html) with [ant-jms](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-jms/).