# Not able to Instantiate the android driver, If the Appium server is started from the code

Tags: android, webdriver, appium

Steps I am following , to start the server is :
**Created a bat file with the below command :**
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node.exe" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/Appium.js" --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 18 --automation-name Appium --no-reset --local-timezone --log  E:\Android\appium.log""

**Code Written to start the server :**

```
public class Testing {
    AppiumDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest

    public void AppiumServerStart() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        String s = null;

        String Filepath = "C:\\appiumserver.bat";

        // String Command = \""C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node.exe"
        // "C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/Appium.js"
        // --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android
        // --platform-version 18 --automation-name Appium --no-reset
        // --local-timezone"\"

        System.out.println(Filepath);

        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Filepath);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(Filepath);
        System.out.println("Server Started");

        Thread.sleep(6000);

}
```

Code to Add Desire Capabilities  and create android driver instance  :

```
public class DemoCalc extends Testing {

    AppiumDriver driver;

    @Test

    public void Setup() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.4");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "169.254.140.101:5555");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.android.calculator2");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```

However , the below exception is thrown on Android driver instance :

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
```

If I manually , start the server by clicking on appium.exe ,then issue does not occur.  But when the server is started from java code issue appears.

After running the  bat file to start the appium server, i see the node process in task manager , which shows the appium server has been connected.

Please help

Comment: When started by bat file, try this url on browser "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"  (replace localhost and port respectively. If you get not a valid resource, then it would mean appium node server is running.

Comment: if i add the local host url , it shows that the appium server is working. Also , if i first run a java code to start a server and then manually , run a selenium code , it works fine . But when i combine this two things together and try to run , it fails with the exception that is given in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Appium server as a separate thread before executing the test.

Comment: I am running a different class to start the server and then i am trying to execute a class which has selenium script . Then also it wont work

Comment: Of course it wont work because the server starter executes the start command and after, finishes the start command and starts executing the tests. But then server is no longer there. You need to **run server parallel** the test execution. So just implement server as parallel task ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218720/running-a-task-in-parallel-to-another-task)).

Comment: i see the node process in task manager , which shows the appium server has been connected.. Appium server remains active , it doesnot get stop. I

Comment: I see the server still running , in cmd even after the server start class finished execution. Which means , server is runs while test is running.