# How to dismiss ProgressDialog after finish all threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have 30 threads (AsyncTask) executed in the same time. Before execute them, I will show progressdialog. After threads finish execution, I will dismiss progressdialog.

Any suggestion on How to dismiss ProgressDialog after finish all threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using exact 30 threads then initialze a variable with 30 and after every task completion decrease the count by one and also check if the variable is zero . if it is zero it indicate that all the tasks has been completed. so you can dismiss the ProgressDialog.

Comment: one will need to run a for loop to continuously check the counter, which will block the UI thread and is not recommended.

Comment: No just write it in onPostexecute() of your async task. so it will check just 30 time. i.e., once for every async task

Comment: also I think the variable should be shared between all thread?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is use an `AsyncTask()` to execute your work and dismiss the dialog in `onPOstExecute()` of it. This will ensure that the task has completed and the ProgressDialog finished. If you still want to continue using Threads , you need to impplement a custom listener which is fired whenever a thread has completed, and you can maintain a counter of how many times it has been fired. I could have given you a code, better example is at this link: [How to know if other threads have finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702415/how-to-know-if-other-threads-have-finished)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a global class:

```
public abstract class Global{

 private static int counter = 30;
 private static ProgressDialog pd;
 private static Activity a;

 public static synchronized void updateCounter(){


 counter--;

 if(counter<=0){

    a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        pd.dismiss();
    }
   });

  }

 }

}
```

you need to use the "synchronized" because of the concurrent access of the threads.

And in your main activity start the ProgressDialog and initialize the variables:

```
Global.a = this;
Global.pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Tittle","Message ...", true);
```

and then start the threads.

On the end of each thread you can then call `Global.updateCounter();`