# How can I tell if a thread is finished?

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know if other threads have finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702415/how-to-know-if-other-threads-have-finished)

I have a threadpool that executes threads for me, how can I tell when ALL the threads I've passed it are done?

For example:

main.java

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
        threadPool.submit(new ThreadHandler(objectArray[i], i));
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
```

ThreadHandler.java

```
public class ThreadHandler implements Runnable {

protected SuperHandler HandlerSH;
protected int threadNum;

public ThreadHandler(SuperHandler superH, int threadNum) {
    this.threadNum = threadNum;
    this.HandlerSH = superH;
}

public void run() {

    //do all methods here

}
```

Would I just put something into the run() section to set a boolean or something?   Would I make an array of boolean to check when they're all done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you submit a job into a thread pool, it returns a [`Future` instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).  You can call `Future.get()` to see if the job has finished.  This is effectively similar to a join on the tasks running in a thread pool.

You can also call `threadPool.awaitTermination(...)` if the thread-pool has been shutdown and you want to wait for *all* of the tasks have finished.

Often when I am submitting a number of jobs into a thread pool, I record their futures in a list:

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
    futures.add(threadPool.submit(new ThreadHandler(objectArray[i], i)));
}
// if we are done submitting, we shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();

// now we can get from the future list or awaitTermination
for (Future<?> future : futures) {
    // this throws an exception if your job threw an exception
    future.get();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `futures` be empty in your example? You don't seem to ever add any to the list.

Comment: I'm thinking he means to do futures.add in his first loop?

Comment: Ooops.  Right.  Fixed.  Thanks guys.