# When is really alive a thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Sorry for the not-very professional question but I am new in Java and thread programming concept. 
If thread is sleep or waitting, is it alive or not? What would return thread.isAlive() True ore False in these two cases?

Comment: I guess trying it and finding out was out of the question? Or even reading the docs?

Comment: This is a lazy Question.  In future, please find and read the available documentation BEFORE you post Questions like this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293304/when-is-a-java-thread-alive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still *alive*, just not running.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29):

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

A thread which is just sleeping or waiting hasn't *died* (it hasn't exited its `run` method, either normally or abruptly), so `isAlive` will return true.

Of course it's very easy to test this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        // Give the new thread plenty of time to really start
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(thread.isAlive());
    }        
}
```

Comment: thread dies when it finish its work (little bit simplified answer and not perfectly correct but it most cases)

Answer (score 1):

A thread is considered to be alive when its start() method has been called. After the run() method finishes, the thread is considered to not be alive anymore.

[Citation](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-determine-if-a-thread-is-alive-or-not.html)