# Clarification about Thread's .isInterrupted(): what is "alive"?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have some trouble understanding what the [javadoc for this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted--) means to say here:

> A thread interruption **ignored because a thread was not alive at the time of the interrupt** will be reflected by this method returning false.

Uhwell, if it's not alive it does not even run, does it? Or it isn't even born in the first place...

So, what does the javadoc want to say here?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293304/when-is-a-java-thread-alive

Comment: @user3575279 yeah, that is what I "surmised"; my problem was with wearing blinders ;)

Answer (score 0):

Uh, OK, as often, after asking a question, I think a little differently and I *think* what the javadoc meant to say here is actually this...

The problem, I believe, is that I'm stuck in the classical paradigm:

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
```

But this is not the only way to have a reference to a `Thread` object. Duh.