# How to set complete or failure to CompletableFuture?

Tags: java

How can I in the method stopTask() set CompletableFuture complete or failure operation if I had an exception in that method?
I have some code:

```
private static class SenderTask implements Runnable {
    private final Sender sender;

    private ScheduledFuture<?> task;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            LOGGER.debug("SenderTask {} calling.", sender.getName());
            sender.process();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }
    }

    public CompletableFuture<SenderTask> stopTask() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            task.cancel(false);
            LOGGER.info("Sender {} try stopping.", sender.getName());
            try {
                    task.get(sender.getSenderConfig().getTimeoutConfig().getSendFileTimeout(),` TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
                    LOGGER.error(e);
                }
                return this;
        });
    }
}
```

I need to know when my task was stopped.

Comment: You could follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661989/how-to-know-when-a-thread-stops-or-is-stopped

Comment: Also https://www.algosome.com/articles/knowing-when-threads-stop.html

Answer (score 0):

Could use handle like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<SenderTask> stopTask() {
   return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      task.cancel(false);
      LOGGER.info("Sender {} try stopping.", sender.getName()); task.get(sender.getSenderConfig().getTimeoutConfig().getSendFileTimeout(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      return this;
  }).handle((res, ex) -> {
      if(ex != null) {
          LOGGER.error(ex);
          ...
      }
      return res;
    });
}
```