# Android java thread not stopping

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have thread in my android app which finish its task but still it is not exit , when I run it again I got error that thread is already alive

my thread

```
    Thread mythreads = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
       // do some work

       // exit point      
}
};
```

so please how can I stop this even thread finish it code execution , but when  I try to run it again it give me error

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started
```

I try to stop with it with my threadkill function code but no success

```
public void killthread(Thread tname){
    try {
        if (tname.isAlive()) {
            Log.d("tag1","Thread is Alive");
            tname.interrupt();
            tname = null;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should understand when a thread is considered [alive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293304/when-is-a-java-thread-alive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread objects are only meant to be started once. If you need to `stop/interrupt` a `Thread`, and then want to start it again, you should create a new instance, and call `start()` on it:

```
thread.interrupt();
thread = new YourThreadSubclass();
thread.start();
```

In your case you are doing `Thread mythreads = new Thread()` so it shouldn't be a problem at all unless you are explicitly trying to stop it before completion of the excecution.

**Creating Anonymous Thread**

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run() {
        //Your code
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: so do you not think that it will create memory issue because after specific time i want to start my thread , and by using your method i have to create every time new object ....... i mean it will use more memory ???

Comment: @user134929 it shouldn't, once you create a new instance of your thread it will mark the old one for garbage collection (unless you have an implicit reference to your context).

Comment: can you tell me how i can create new instance of my thread , i mean i start my thread  mythreads.start();   it completed and still alive so how to create new instance ?? please help

Comment: @user134929 Create an Anonymous thread and you won't face any issues. I'll update it in my code.