# How do I test the completion of threads created under my testmethod in JUnit

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I have a method `createThreads` which spawns few new threads. Each of the newly created thread does some work. If I invoke the method `createThreads' in junit, how can i ensure that all the newly spawned threads have also completed successfully.

I am currently calling as below

```
@Test
public void test() {
    createThreads();  // Does not wait until the newly created threads also finish.    
}


public void createThreads()
{
ExecutorService executorService = Executors
        .newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
               Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("I have completed execution " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
}
```

Note that I cannot modify `createThreads`

Comment: How about adding those threads to a List and check whether they completed or not. and make sure to wait till completed

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702415/how-to-know-if-other-threads-have-finished

Comment: do you have access to ExecutorService?

Comment: @Reddy I do not have access to those threads. But I only know that some are getting created.

Comment: @user1121883: No, I do not have access to ExecutorService and the method does not return anything

Answer (score 2):

a bit odd but..

you can probably get all the runing threads

through `Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();`
then filter it to identify the thread from the executor service.
then do a .join() on each of those threads.

as i said, a bit odd but it should fit your needs ...

Comment: I do not have access to the executor service, so I cannot filter and identify such threads

Answer (score 0):

try running this, you'll see that they are quite easy to identify :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int nb = 3;
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nb);
    for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("I have completed execution " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        });

    }


    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    for (Thread t : threadSet) {
        System.out.println(t.getName());
    }

}
```

sorry for a 2nd answer not possible to add such a long code in comment