# Java Swingworker one after another and update GUI

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am working on java swing with some multithreaded application. The situation is so, that I need to execute one thread after another i.e I output of one is related to the second. I did the following.

```
// Class one
public class Samp implements Runnable{
    public Samp(String name) {
       this.setName = name;
    }
    public void run (){
      // Here I have a file extraction method called
      extract(this.getName);
    }

   // Extract Method
   public Boolean extract(String filename){
     // Some extraction Operation.
     // I want to update the jTextField with the current filename under     extraction.
   }
}
```

// the GUI Class

```
public class Welcome extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>worker =  new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ZipUtility(fileName));
            t1.start();
            return true;
        }

        // Can safely update the GUI from this method.
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            // Here when this worker is done I wanted to Run worker 2
        }
    };

    SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>worker2 = .........

   // Again when worker2 is done I wanted to run worker 3 and so on.    
 }
```

My Questions are :

1) How to run all the workers in a perfect sequencial order. i.e when worker1 is done then start worker 2, when worker2 is done then start worker 3 and so on.

2) How to update a textfield in  my Welcome class, with the values from the Samp  class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a fixed thread executor and add your workers to them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702415/how-to-know-if-other-threads-have-finished

Comment: Why are you starting a thread from a worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) How to run all the workers in a perfect sequencial order. i.e when worker1 is done then start worker 2, when worker2 is done then start worker 3 and so on.

A little trick to remember, you can put a `SwingWorker` into a `ExecutorService`

So, using something like...

```
public static class Worker extends SwingWorker {

    private int sequence;

    public Worker(int sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(sequence + "...");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        return null;
    }

}
```

As a test, you could use something like...

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    es.submit(new Worker(index));
}
es.shutdown();
```

*(You don't need to call `shutdown`, but otherwise my tested never allowed the JVM to terminate ;))*

Which will run the workers in the order they are submitted.

Now, if you want to feed the values from one `SwingWorker` to another, you could do something like...

```
public abstract class ChainedWorker<T, V> extends SwingWorker<T, V> {

    private ChainedWorker<T, ?> next;
    private T previousValue;

    public ChainedWorker(ChainedWorker<T, ?> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setPreviousValue(T previousValue) {
        this.previousValue = previousValue;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            T previous = get();
            if (next != null) {
                next.setPreviousValue(previous);
                next.execute();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Which is simply a `SwingWorker` which allows you to provide a link in the chain (the next worker to call), which passes the value that this `SwingWorker` generated...or some such similar

Now, if you're really nuts and want to role your own, maybe something like...

```
public class ChainedWorkerBuilder {

    private List<SwingWorker> workers;
    private SwingWorker current;

    public ChainedWorkerBuilder() {
        workers = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public ChainedWorkerBuilder add(SwingWorker worker) {
        workers.add(worker);
        return this;
    }

    public void execute() {
        if (!workers.isEmpty()) {
            SwingWorker worker = workers.remove(0);
            worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if ("state".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        SwingWorker source = (SwingWorker)evt.getSource();
                        switch (source.getState()) {
                            case DONE:
                                source.removePropertyChangeListener(this);
                                execute();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

> 2) How to update a textfield in my Welcome class, with the values from the Samp class.

I don't think I'm following your code directly, but, if you did something like...

```
SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>worker =  new SwingWorker<Boolean, String>() {

    protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
        publish(fileName);
        ZipUtility zu = new ZipUtility(fileName));
        return zu.extract(fileName);
    }
```

Then in the `SwingWorker`s `process` method you would be able to update the UI safely...

```
    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        // Grab the last element...
        textfield.setText(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `execute()` on `worker2` from `worker1`'s done:

```
final SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> worker2 =  new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>() {
   ...
}

final SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> worker1 =  new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // Don't start a thread, do your work, otherwise the done will fire
        // too early, also it's pointless to use worker and thread like that
        return true;
    }

    // Can safely update the GUI from this method.
    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // update some ui
        // and start the second part
        worker2.execute();
    }
};
```