# Detecting if a thread is running in java fx

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have tried three approaches and I couldn't get any to work. I took a lot of my code from the top answer to this post [How to know if other threads have finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702415/how-to-know-if-other-threads-have-finished) I followed #5 on that list pretty closely. Here is my issue: From my main thread I need to be able to detect if the secondary thread is running when a button is pressed.

1st Approach

```
NotifyThread task = null;

@FXML
private void handleButtonPress(ActionEvent event){
if (thread == null){
     NotifyThread thread = new Thread2(1,0);
}
else{
    //task is already running 
    thread.end()
}
```

The problem with the above code is that thread is always null. Instead of ending the existing thread it creates another one that runs alongside (bad)

2nd Approach

```
if (thread.isAlive())
```

3rd Approach

```
if(thread.getState.equals(RUNNABLE))
```

Both of these methods give me runtime exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
  thread = new Thread2(1,0);
```

Instead of

```
  NotifyThread thread = new Thread2(1,0);
```

Comment: Good catch. I was just going off the link I posted where he said to do NotifyingThread thread1 = new OneOfYourThreads();