# Java : Thread Programming, Thread Sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a master thread which has its own child threads. Each thread is given a process to be performed and that particular thread must sleep after its work is done until the next frequency of thread awakening.

I have implemented the whole section of code, but not able to make the thread sleep as I'm not aware of is the job of that thread is done or not, in order to make it sleep until the next frequency time.

1. Create Maste Thread
2. Create child threads for each processes from the DB.
3. For Each Child Thread Process, it checks its runtime and next runtime to perform the job.
4. Make the thread sleep after the work is done until the next runtime.
5. Go to Step 3.

I'm stuck at 4, to check if the threads have done its job or not. ( here the child thread doesn't say, if its work is done or not, we have it make it sleep after work is done)

Can anyone help, how it can be done?

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService stp = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(11);

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${con.fixedDelay}")
public void processServices() {

    try {

        logger.debug("Entering processServices in MasterProcessThread ");

        // Getting process details and schedule
        List<ProcessDomain> activeProcessList = processDomainDao.getActiveProcessDomainSchedule();

        logger.info("getDomainData for flag is Active :: " + activeProcessList.size());

        // Iterating over active processList to create child threads
        for (ProcessDomain activeProcessDomain : activeProcessList) {

            Timestamp nextRunTS = activeProcessDomain.getProcessSchedule().getProcessNextRunScheduleTime();

            Long nextRunTime = (nextRunTS != null ? nextRunTS.getTime() : null);
            Long startTS = activeProcessDomain.getProcessSchedule().getProcessScheduleTime().getTime();
            Long currentTS = System.currentTimeMillis();
            boolean isPreviousRunSucc = (activeProcessDomain.getProcessRunHistory().getPreviousSuccFlag() != null
                    && activeProcessDomain.getProcessRunHistory().getPreviousSuccFlag().equals("Y")) ? true : false;
            Future future = null;

            // Initializing the child threads and start processing
            if (((nextRunTime == null && currentTS >= startTS) || (nextRunTime != null && currentTS >= nextRunTime))
                    && isPreviousRunSucc) {
                Callable task = beanServiceThreadFactory.getBeanThread(activeProcessDomain.getProcessName(),
                        activeProcessDomain);
                future = stp.submit(task);
                if (future.isDone()){
                    stp.shutdown();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Consider a library, like: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/ or Spring

Comment: Please provide what you've already tried.

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702415/how-to-know-if-other-threads-have-finished

Comment: Use an Executors thread pool. Create an abstract Process class that extends Runnable and provides a boolean isDue() method. The master thread iterates through a List of Process instances and submits them to the thread pool if the are due

Comment: `Thread.sleep()`may help...

Comment: Like @DavidW said, but use a`ScheduledExecutor` to run the tasks regularly.

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Please check the updated desc.

Comment: @daniu I already has implemented the ScheduledExecutor

Comment: @Benoit I want the thread to sleep until the next frequency call, i.e., next run time, once the job has been done

Comment: What do you think the thread does when the process it started has terminated?

Comment: @daniu That is what I'm not able out to figure out.