# How to execute a treatment in the background?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, for-loop, background

How can I optimize a java treatment (for loop, nested loop) and execute it in the background so I can continue with another treatment?

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,
        readOnly = false, rollbackFor = AppTechnicalException.class)
public void update(FicheDTO dto, String code) throws {
    Fiche fiche = this.ficheDAO.find(fiche.getNumero());

    this.traitementToDO(dto, fiche);

    Tracabilite trace = createTraceF(fiche.getNumero(), code);
}
```

I want that `this.traitementToDO(dto, fiche)` to run in the background!

Comment: Start here: [Asynchronous Programming in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-asynchronous-programming)

Answer (score 0):

In order to compute multiple tasks in parallel in Java, you can use threads. By creating a new thread you can run your long tasks asynchronously and then notify when the execution of your tasks is done.
For more info about threads, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702415/how-to-know-if-other-threads-have-finished).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = AppTechnicalException.class)
public void update(FicheDTO dto, String code) throws {

    Fiche fiche = this.ficheDAO.find(fiche.getNumero()) ;

    Thread demonThread = new Thread(() -> traitementToDO(dto, fiche));
    /*new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            traitementToDO(dto, fiche);
        }
    }); //lambda like anonimus class */

    daemonThread.setDaemon(true); // run as demon if needed
    daemonThread.start(); // execute method in another child thread
    

    Tracabilite trace = createTraceF(fiche.getNumero(), code);
}
```

**BUT**
Think about @Transactional:
If you need to cover `traitementToDO` by transaction, you cannot call it via `this`, because you have no access to spring proxy inside this bean. So you need to do self autowiring and then call it via `self.traitementToDO`. Also, be careful with custom multithreading if you don't know how to use Threads. Finally, you need to read how to use @Transactional in multithreading (if you need to cover `traitementToDO` by transaction again).

Comment: yes I tried and i cover my traitementToDO with @Transactionnal but  does not  commit :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of some objects, you can *parallelize* their processing with a [`parallel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) stream like this:

```java
List<FicheDTO> list = List.of(...);
String code = "UPDATE ...";

list.stream().parallel().forEach(dto -> update(dto, code));
```